# Proving something isn't isomorphic, $\varphi : 5\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to see if I can find a bijection between two groups that are infinite of which one in the subset of the other. If I find the inverse $\phi^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{5}x$ since it doesn't work for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ (because I will have values in $\mathbb{Q}$) then there isn't an isomorphism right?

Or have I approached the problem incorrectly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have $\phi$ in the title but $f$ in the body.  What is your proposed bijection?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Sorry I messed the mapping up I meant to put $\phi$ in the body as well. I'm trying to find a bijection to show that it is isomorphic. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @dls: Since your question was answered, would you mind to **accept** the answer?

Comment: @Moritz sorry I'm new still. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}$ are given by $n\Bbb{Z}$. For $n\neq 0$, $n\Bbb{Z}$ is an infinite cyclic group with generator $n$, and hence isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$. You do not necessarily need to find an explicit isomorphism (assuming you had cyclic groups in class already). So in fact $5\Bbb{Z}\cong \Bbb{Z}$, in contrast to your title.

Comment: Thank for the concept. I was asked to prove this and my idea was to find a function.

Comment: @dls But you wrote "isn't isomorphic" in your title, so you wanted to show that there is no such "function"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, at first I thought it wasn't isomorphic. Then I began to think it was isomorphic and your comment confirmed it.

Comment: @dls No problem:)

Answer (score 0):

The inverse is not defined on the whole set, but only on the subset so it is a good argument. You can define $\phi:5\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ by $\phi(z)={1\over 5}z$.

Comment: I don't get that answer. It seems to me the issue is quite different. Namely that the inverse is determined incorrectly.

Comment: That's the "inverse" of what exactly?

Comment: To define a map, you need to define its domain, here the domain is $5\mathbb{Z}$, no $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide I see I mixed it up then the inverse is going to be $\phi^{-1}(z)=5z$ right? If I plug numbers from my codomain then I get numbers in my domain and reverse then right?

Comment: yes, it is exactly that.

Comment: This answer uses "inverse" in a way that is distinct to the way it is used in the question, which makes it confusing.